# Python source compile in windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, python-3.x

By default Python 3.3 installers are built with Visual studio 2010.
I have visual studio 2013 and I want to generate the python33.dll from visual studio 2013.
When i link my application with dll generated from visual studio 2013 then it is getting crash in "Py_Initialize" function but when i link my application with dll generated from visual studio 2010 then everything works fine.

I have tried to build from source with VS2013. Going into "PCBuild" folder and try to build Python33.dll from .sln file but application is getting crashed.

How to make application run without crash with visual studio 2013 dll ?
Is there any steps to compile the Python source code in MinGW in windows ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you built python33.dll yourself in vs2013, you are easily able to debug py_initialize. That's where you should begin.